# only special characters remove from the list

Tags: python, regex, list

From a pdf file I extract all the text as a string, and convert it into the list by removing all the double white spaces, newlines (two or more), spaces (if two or more), and on every dot (.).
Now in my list I want, if a value of a list consists of only special characters, that value should be excluded.

```html
pdfFileObj = open('Python String.pdf', 'rb') 
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
text=pageObj.extractText()
z =re.split("\n+|[.]|\s{2,}",text)
while("" in z) :
    z.remove("")
print(z)
```

**My output is**

```html
['split()', 'method in Python split a string into a list of strings after breaking the', 'given string by the specified separator', 'Syntax', ':', 'str', 'split(separator, maxsplit)', 'Parameters', ':', 'separator', ':', 'This is a delimiter', ' The string splits at this specified separator', ' If is', 'no', 't provided then any white space is a separator', 'maxsplit', ':', 'It is a number, which tells us to split the string into maximum of provi', 'ded number of times', ' If it is not provided then the default is', '-', '1 that means there', 'is no limit', 'Returns', ':', 'Returns a list of s', 'trings after breaking the given string by the specifie', 'd separator']
```

Here are some values that contain only special characters and I want to remove those. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression that tests if a string contains any letters or numbers.

```
import re

z = [x for x in z if re.search(r'[a-z\d]', x, flags=re.I)]
```

In the regexp, `a-z` matches letters, `\d` matches digits, so `[a-z\d]` matches any letter or digit (and the `re.I` flag makes it case-insensitive). So the list comprehension includes any elements of `z` that contain a letter or digit.

Answer (score 2):

Remove those special characters before converting text to list.
remove `while("" in z) : z.remove("")` and add following line after read `text` variable:

```
text = re.sub('(a|b|c)', '', text)
```

In this example, my special characters are a, b and c.

Comment: The question wasn't how to remove special characters, it was how to remove the elements of the list that only contain special characters.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But at the title and the end of the question removing "special characters" mentioned. I think my answer is right too. Sometimes one problem has many solutions :) Anyway, your answer is right and accepted as the best answer. I have no objection. Congratulations :)